# "Card contains invalid attachment count" exception in Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm getting an exception "*Card contains invalid attachment count*" when adding a lot of choices to `PromptOptions` parameter of `ChoicePrompt`. Let's say that in the following sample, the GetChoices() methods will returns an array with 90 values:

```
var promptOptions = new PromptOptions
{
    Prompt = TemplateEngine.GenerateActivityForLocale("AskChoiceMessage"),
    RetryPrompt = TemplateEngine.GenerateActivityForLocale("AskAgainChoiceMessage"),
    Choices = GetChoices(),
    Style = ListStyle.HeroCard
};

return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ChoicePrompt), promptOptions, cancellationToken);
```

I know that the Teams channel is rendering the Herocard as a carousel with 6 value for each "page". I don't know if there is also a limit on the number of allowed pages for a carousel.

What is the exact maximum number of allowed choices to pass to ChoicePrompt to have them rendered correctly in Teams?

PS: it could also be useful to know the value for all the other channels.

Answer (score 1):

After some test I found the following:

- there can be max 6 buttons per HeroCard (See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#properties-of-a-hero-card))
- so, in Teams, ChoicePrompt with longer list is rendered  as a Carousel of HeroCard with 5 buttons each (why not 6?)
- the maximum number of HeroCard per carousel "seems" to be 10 (Empirically tested. There is nothing [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#carousel-collection) about this point).

So 50 max buttons in total are allowed.

Other references [here](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/3315) and [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/908686-bug-reports/suggestions/38572720-adaptive-cards-carousel-not-displaying-in-teams).